# .htaccess redirect rule does not work (nothing happens) when used with rewirite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to rewrite an old URL to a new one with .htaccess and in the same time redirect any requests from the old to the new one.

My rewrite rule works great but when I add a redirect rule nothing happens.

May I ask you to look into the code and let me know what needs to be changed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/page$ /old_page.php?mode=2 [L]

Redirect /old_page.php?mode=2 /new/page
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+old_page\.php\?mode=2
RewriteRule ^ /new/page? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/page$ /old_page.php?mode=2 [L]
```

Two reasons you can't use `Redirect`:

1. You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect`
2. You're matching what you've rewritten. This will cause a redirect loop.

So you need to match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable instead.

Comment: Thank you for the working code and the explanation for it. Now I know where I got it wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set AllowOverride All in your  tag in apache